# Thread pool in ASP.Net regularly shutting down

Tags: asp.net, threadpool

In my ASP.Net app, the thread pool is getting regularly shut down. This isn't a fixed interval but happens randomly, usually once a week. It's like the pool crashes. What bothers me is that I have to restart it manually. As long as the pool is shut down, the app is not available. How can I figure out what is causing this and how can I have the pool automatically restart if it ever does crash?

Comment: What do you mean, "the thread pool gets shut down"? What is the symptom of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the startMode attribute of an application pool using IIS Manager

In IIS Manager, click computer name in the Connection pane.
Switch to Features View if the view is not active.
Double-click Configuration Editor in the Management section of the Features View.
Click the down-arrow for the Section field, expand system.applicationhost, and then click application pools.
Click (Collection) and then click eclipses (…) next to the field that shows the count.
In the Collection Editor, select the application pool for which you want to configure the startMode attribute.
In the Properties window at the bottom, set the value of startMode attribute to AlwaysRunning.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Was setting this on the actual pool and not through the configuration manager. Not sure why settings on the actual pool don't override the settings in Configuration Manager.